# Retrict reservation for day of week & time am pm

Tags: php

I want to do allow online reservation on following day of week and timings **Saturday 3 to 8 PM** ,
i just made this function so getting **dayOfTheWeek** , but how to check if 3 to 8 PM , then restrict , why my condition is not working

```
function can_do_reservation($dateTime){
    
    $timestamp = "2021-06-19 11:37:00";
    
    $dateTime1 = new DateTime($timestamp, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')); 
    //$dateTime1 = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')); 
    $currentTime=$dateTime1->format("h:i A"); 
    //echo $currentTime;
    
    
    $saturdayStartTime = new DateTime('2021-06-19 15:00:00',new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
    //echo $saturdayStartTime1=$saturdayStartTime->format("h:i A"); exit;
    $saturdayEndTime = new DateTime('2021-06-19 20.00:00',new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
    $dayOfTheWeek = intval($dateTime->format('N'));
    
    //print_r($saturdayEndTime);
    $message=null;
    if ($dayOfTheWeek === 6) {
        if ($currentTime > $saturdayStartTime && $currentTime < $saturdayEndTime) {
            $message= "It's and we are open!";
        }else{
            $message= "Restaurant doesn’t allow online reservation on following day of week and timings. Sorry for the Inconvenience.";
        }
    }

    return  $message;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i have refactored some bits so use what you need:

```
function can_do_reservation( $dateTime ){
    
    $dayOfTheWeek = intval( $dateTime->format('N') );

    if ( $dayOfTheWeek === 6 ) 
    {
        $currentTime = new DateTime( null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
        $startTime   = new DateTime('15:00',new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
        $endTime     = new DateTime('20.00',new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));

        if ( ( $currentTime > $startTime ) && ( $currentTime < $endTime ) ) 
        {
            return "It's and we are open!";
        } 
        else
        {
            return "Restaurant doesn’t allow online reservation on following day of week and timings. Sorry for the Inconvenience.";
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```